# How to reveal current document in File browser in TM2 like the Project drawer in TM1?

Tags: editor, textmate, textmate2

*Ctrl-Cmd-R* in TM1 used to reveal the location of the current file in the project drawer. This was a very useful feature in textmate.

TM2 has the same shortcut and call its '**Current document**' and works very similarly, but it also changes the current directory in the **File browser** (the new Project drawer equivalent in TM2 I think). This is not very useful as I would like to keep my project root open in the File browser.

Also if I tried to navigate back to the project root by using *Ctrl-Tab* (Focus on File drawer), and *Cmd + Up Arrow* (Move to parent directory), then file drawer goes back to the original state and does not have the required file "revealed" in the File Browser.

Has anyone managed to get around this? I would like a behavior similar to TM1.(also found in most IDEs/editors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `.tm_properties` file in your project root and add this line:

```
projectDirectory = "$CWD"
```

That way TM2 knows to perform all file search related queries from the path, so when using cmd+T you'll not only see matches from the current root in the finder/project drawer.

If you want to navigate the project using the finder/project drawer use the same keys as in Finder.

Comment: Yep, the former works. But that was not my question/problem. Trying Ctrl+Cmd+R with a file nested a few levels currently in focus on the editor. You will notice, the Project drawer switched to the directory where the file is located, and keep that file in selection. I wanted this particular action to NOT lose the projectDirectory selection. In other words, reveal the file but, keep the directory root the same in the drawer.

Comment: @jake for visual orientation?

Comment: Typically because I would want to create a new file in the same folder as the file in current view. Also sometimes to just be aware of where the file is wrt to the project root. Example partials in a Rails project etc.

Comment: @jake 2013-01-13 (r9345) this version should fix your problem.